# Migrating NSFetchedResultsController to UIViewController from UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In order to circumvent some problems inherent to NSFetchedResultsController, I decided to change my UITableViewController to a UIViewController and just add a tableView property. I am not using storyboards and I am making everything programmatically. The goal of this is to have a table view that leaves about 44 px of empty space (so I can put a universal header there) on the y axis from the top. Basically, I am trying to shift the tableview down by 44 px.

The problem is, I am getting breakpoint errors at the fetchedResultsController. Here is my code:

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ToDoViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, SettingsViewControllerDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ToDoViewController
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        UINavigationItem *i = [self navigationItem];
        [i setTitle:@"Task List"];
_tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 548) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
        self.tableView = self.fetchedResultsController.delegate;

    }
    return self;


-(void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);
    } 

    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];

    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:baseColor];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:baseColor];

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Tasks" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *isCompleted = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"sectionString" ascending:NO];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"dateCreated" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[isCompleted, sort]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionString"
                                                   cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

The problem is that the table view is not getting populated with the items that are supposed to be fetched by the nsfetchedresultscontroller. I don't know why this is...maybe because the tableview isn't the delegate or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate is used for monitoring changes to core data entities so you don't need

```
    self.tableView = self.fetchedResultsController.delegate;
```

You need to implement the UITableViewDelegate methods using the NSFetchedResultsController. Mainly

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController.sections objectAtIndex:section];
    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

Note: after you create your NSFetchedResultsController, you also have to call performFetch:

You can see a great example of implementing all of this by using the Master-Detail template and having "Use Core Data" checked.

Comment: I feel like the problem is that I am adding a the tableview as a subview and the NSFC doesn't know to send it to the tableview

Comment: The NSFC does not send data to the tableview, it just contains the data. The tableview should be asking your view controller to supply the data through the UITableViewDataSource Protocol.

Comment: If I try to create a XIB instead of create the tableview programmatically, the tableview doesn't load. I'm not sure why

Comment: Put the setup code for the tableview in viewDidLoad, see if that helps

Comment: No problem, I guess initWithNibName wasn't being called for some reason or was being called after viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

For me, coming from a UITableViewController going to a UIViewController containing a UITableView, I had to do the following to get NSFetchedResultsController to work:

1. made the view controller handle delegate methods for UITableView and UITableViewDataSource:

   @interface UIViewControllerName : UIViewController  < UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
2. set the delegate and datasource of the UITableView (In my case I called it tableView using outlet from the storyboard) to self (in viewDidLoad in my case)

   ```
   [super viewDidLoad];

   self.tableView.delegate = self;
   self.tableView.dataSource = self;

   appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   self.managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

   NSError *error;
   if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
       // handle error
       NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
       exit(-1); // fail
   }
   ```